# scale in graphicx don´t work when width set with setkeys

Tags: graphics, tufte

I am editing a document using  graphicx with width options set by setkey, as in

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
```

The problem is that when I want to specifically resize a picture with scale option, it does not work. Therefore

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{anypic.png}
```

Has no effect at all. It seems to be overriden by the width.

There is any way to make graphicx forget the width for one specific figure?

Obs: resetting the width of the figure works, but I would like to avoid measuring figures.

Comment: Why not `width=0.5\linewidth`?

Comment: What does 'measuring' mean? Do you want to 'scale' the 'true size' of some images while others just get scaled to `\linewidth`? How do you know what to scale them without 'measuring'?

Comment: First, a wish to see the command working. Second, it seems more natural to work with scale than.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an exclamation to reset the width and height values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-A}

\includegraphics[width=!,totalheight=!,scale=0.5]{example-image-A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in the preamble, and I write something before the second `includegraphics`, like `dfhg \includegraphics[width=!,totalheight=!,scale=0.5]{example-image-A}` I got errors. Any ideas why, and what I can do ?

Comment: @antoine french makes the ! active to insert small spaces (when inside a paragraph so you have a problem only if a paragraph has been started). Use either `\shorthandoff{!}` before the graphic, or `width=\detokenize{!}`.